# не работает правильно аниматор

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Сделал код где если игра окончена, то *должна* происходит анимация с появлением UI компонента. Но дело в том что анимация после выполнения условия не работает и почему то ругается что в инспекторе не добавлена анимация. В коде как и в аниматоре всё стоит как нужно, и всё равно не работает. Работает только в том случае если в самом аниматоре не переключить значение с **False** на **True**

код

```
 public void PlayAnimation()
 {
     animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

     if (animator != null)
     {
         animator.SetBool("IsStart", true);
     }
     
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**как должно работать**
После проверки (если у противника\игрока<=0 здоровья) вызывается PlayAnimation()